# Rails view submit parameter to controller method defined by me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

How can I write a form in the view which calls a controller method I've defined? Also, I want to pass a parameter to the method. I want to do something like this, where I have defined the method `predict`, which takes the parameter `days`.

```
<%=form_for @currency, url: url_for(:controller => :currencies, :action => :predict) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :days %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :days %>
    <%= f.submit "Predict", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<%end%>
```

Also, what do I need to add in `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

The 'rails way' would say not to create custom actions but create a new `Predictions` controller and use a standard `:new` or `:create` action depending on what you want.

That being said, you can use

```
<%=form_for @currency, url: {action: "predict"} do |f| %>
<%= f.label :days %><br />
<%= f.text_field :days %>
<%= f.submit "Predict", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

You can find it in these docs by searching for "action:" http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

You'll then have access the `params[:days]` or however you set up your strong params. Hope this helps!

Comment: I get the error: undefined method `days' for #<Currency:0x007fc5c373a790>

Answer (score 0):

I generated a scaffold Currency with only one column (days) :

```
rails generate scaffold Currency days:string
```

In my Currency controller you have two action (home for the form and the root path and predict) :

```
class CurrenciesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @currency = Currency.new
  end

  def predict
    puts params[:currency][:days]
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

The home view with the form looks like this :

```
<%= form_for @currency, :url => url_for(:controller => 'currencies', :action => 'predict') do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :days %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :days %>
    <%= f.submit "Predict", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

With this result you can see the days field printed in your console with the `puts` log.

My routes.rb looks like this :

```
get 'currencies/home'
post 'currencies/predict'
root 'currencies#home'
```